# Nested Reference of Application Settings in Function App

Tags: azure-function-app

Is there a way to reference an Function App Application Setting in another Application Setting. In the example below I have an Application Setting with an EventHubKey. The content of that setting is inserted into the second Application Setting called EventHubConnectionString.

EventHubKey: wHBhcHdvga28JbvfWnZgmFt94RB+RAZfP+Cq0WtUooiM=

EventHubConnectionString: Endpoint=sb://myevh.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=**ReferTo:EventHubKey**;EntityPath=e1

Comment: There is no way to do this. Values in app config is treated similar to an environment variable and it is constant. You can use key vault though if you want to hide the secret. But you would have to hide the whole connection string.

Comment: Shariful, that is correct. I also verified this with Microsoft support.